# Existe el Insert Update en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber si en MySQL existe la instrucción de Insert Update, algo que supiera que si ese registro ya existe en mi tabla lo actualice y sino que cree uno nuevo y en caso de existir, como se maneja ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba a utilizar :

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Un ejemplo de consulta utilizando esto sería:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name="A", age=19
```

Esta respuesta ha sido traducida de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205207/3683321) de StackOverflow en inglés.

Para más información visita la sección [14.2.5.3 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) de MySql.

Answer (score 5):

Te dejo una alternativa a la de @Joacer, que es la de la sentencia [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html), la cual su sintáxis es igual que la de insert,la cual en tablas con `Auto Increment` continúa la numeración, mientras que de la manera que sugiere @Joacer existe [un pequeño problema con el `Auto Increment` que hace que se salte el número](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516958/on-duplicate-key-auto-increment-issue-mysql?answertab=active#tab-top).

`on duplicate key` aplicaría un auténtico update, mientras que `REPLACE` te haría un `DELETE` y un `INSERT` en duplicados. (Lo cual te puede dar un problema si tienes el id en otras tablas como llaves foráneas)

Como puedes ver ambas tienen sus ventajas y desventajas.

Saludos

Comment: esta alternativa no la conocía, muy buena aportación!

Answer (score 3):

La resolución más amigable a esto es utilizar la claúsula **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**, siempre que la tabla a la cual estas intentando ingresar una fila posee **Clave Primaria**.

Suponiendo que tenes la tabla ***Clientes*** con los campos: **Num**, Nombre, Telefono. (Num es Clave Primaria)

Insertaras con la siguiente sentencia:

```
INSERT INTO Clientes(Num, Nombre, Telefono) VALUES(1,'Agustin','123456') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Telefono = VALUES(Telefono);
```

La claúsula **DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** seguida del Campo = y aquí puedes colocar VALUES(Telefono) para no tener que repetir nuevamente el valor '123456'.